# IIS High CPU Usage in Visual Studio 2013

Tags: iis, visual-studio-2013, iis-express

When we use Visual Studio 2013 for web development, we experience the following issues while debugging:

1. Web application takes a very long time to load
2. Client scripts take a long time to load
3. CPU usage by the IIS worker process increases enormously while debugging the application

Changing to a local IIS does not solve these problems.

What's going on here?

Comment: Reviving the dead here but I'm having the same problem. None of the answers below have been the problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to this site  https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/T102322

In Microsoft Visual Studio 2013, the **Browser Link** feature was introduced. It provides dynamic exchange between IDE and any open browser on your machine. With the help of this feature, you can test changes in page markup in browsers on the fly, inspect HTML objects, etc. However, the use of this feature might cause abovementioned problems in the debugging process.

A common solution is to **disable** Browser Link in Visual Studio:

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much! My project has been spiking CPU usage and making my website crawl. I've changed so many project settings with no luck but this worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

For me, this was happening because I use Resharper and have a big file oppened (30k lines). I just disable resharper for some specific files.